# MATLAB keyboard shortcuts on UNIX

Tags: java, matlab, unix, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to change the keyboard shortcuts (bindings) for Matlab on Unix to be as in Windows. The solution for this should be through Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts and then change the Emacs settings to Windows settings. However, when I try to open it, it does not load and it gives the following error:

```
PrefsDialog: unable to find class
com.mathworks.mlwidgets.prefs.binding.KeyboardShortcutsPrefPanel, with method createPrefsPanel.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
com.mathworks.mlwidgets.prefs.PrefsPanelWrapper.createPanel(PrefsPanelWrapper.java:137) at
com.mathworks.mlwidgets.prefs.PrefsPanelWrapper.getComponent(PrefsPanelWrapper.java:94)
...
```

Comment: Did you check this link? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98454

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, it checked it before but the answer was not helpful (at least in my case) since the only classpath.txt I found was $MATLABROOT\toolbox\local\classpath.txt.